# sum mqtt values with node-red

Tags: node-red

from MQTT feed I got thous values:

```
06/08/2018, 01:59:06View all 'emon/#' MQTT traffic
emon/emontx3/power1 : msg.payload : string [3]
588

emon/emontx3/power2 : msg.payload : string [3]
354

emon/emontx3/power3 : msg.payload : string [3]
740
```

how I can write function or use another node-red node to sum thous values to one ( 588+354+740=1682 )

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I am having the same question. Seems to be easy but I can't find the way how to do that.

Comment: Please take a look at this article, which shows how to sum values:
https://medium.com/node-red/understanding-node-red-flows-64e37f2777fb 
It is not complete answer but hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the 3 power values of the emonTx node being sent as 3 separate MQTT messages, it would be better to get it sent as a single MQTT message.

Eg in my setup, I got managed to get it sent as:

> {"topic":"emonhub/rx/10/values","payload":"180,-209,37,1,261","qos":0,"retain":false,"_msgid":"a142b96c.e678d8"}

FYI I have used the following code in my node-red function node to parse the above MQTT message:

```
var parts        = msg.payload.split(",");
var CT1_power    = parseFloat(parts[0]);
var CT2_power    = parseFloat(parts[1]);
var CT3_power    = parseFloat(parts[2]);
var solar_power  = parseFloat(parts[3]);
var voltage      = parseFloat(parts[4]);
var phase1_power = CT1_power + solar_power;
var phase2_power = - CT2_power;
var phase3_power = CT3_power;
var total_power  = phase1_power + phase2_power + phase3_power;
msg.payload = { "total_power"  : total_power,
                "solar_power"  : solar_power,
                "voltage"      : voltage,
                "phase1_power" : phase1_power,
                "phase2_power" : phase2_power,
                "phase3_power" : phase3_power,
                "CT1_power"    : CT1_power,
                "CT2_power"    : CT2_power,
                "CT3_power"    : CT3_power,
};
return msg;
```

In my case "total_power" in the output msg.payload is the sum of the power used by the 3 phases measured by the emonTx node.

Comment: I try to put my info to your example @JanVdA, yet without success  :)

Comment: Hi @Margus, i don’t understanding your comment?   Can you explain it a bit more ?

Comment: Hi @JanVdA -first sorry I think my english is not so good, but what I meant, is I almost understand Your example, but I can't but my data fit with your example, to get my think works like I want - to sum my three phases to get total power.

Comment: Can you give some details about how your data is produced and sent as mqtt message and what you exactly did to make it fit with my example.  You can add this extra information at the bottom of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are the 3 messages reliably sent at about the same time with a decent gap between groups of messages? If so, you could just use a join node to combine the three messages into one. Then a subsequent change node or function node could add the values (see below). If not, you could store the values in flow variables until they're needed. However, you would need to know the conditions on which to add them.

[image]

Comment: I giving a try - but Yes all the topics coming at the same time max 1 sec delay



  [1]: https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0v5DyOeFBwKe-Lu_-w_8UT3qA#Screen_Shot_2018-08-30_at_07.58.30.png